# PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.text features attribute in Pillow 7.0.0 dosen't seem to give any difference in results

Tags: image, formatting, python-imaging-library, drawtext, opentype

This is the code

```
img = np.full(shape=(40, 225, 3), fill_value=211, dtype=np.uint8)
b,g,r,a = 0,0,0,0
fontpath = "arial.ttf"     
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 14)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
draw.text((25, 10), captcha, font=font, features=['cpsp', 'dist'],  fill=(b, g, r, a))
# w=img_pil.rotate(17.5,  expand=1)
# img_pil = Image.paste( ImageOps.colorize(w, (0,0,0), (255,255,84)), (242,60),  w)
img = np.array(img_pil)
noise_factor = np.random.uniform(low=0.4, high=0.8, size=1)
gauss = np.random.normal(0, noise_factor, img.size)
gauss = gauss.reshape(img.shape[0],img.shape[1],img.shape[2]).astype('uint8')
noise = img + img * gauss
## Display 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(noise, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(captcha+".png", gray)
```

The above code didn't alter the space between the characters, am I using it right?
Please include some examples in https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html on how to use this.
[Click Here to see the output for the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfTyV.png)

Comment: "Requires libraqm". Do you have that library? (Also – possibly unrelated –, my up to date version of Arial does not have a `dist` feature, although it does have `cpsp`.)

Comment: yes there are no dependency issues, I already apt installed libraqm. Oh so options like dist, cpsp... are dependent on if the ttf file support them?

Comment: Not "the ttf file", the opentype font you're using. `dist`, `cpsp`, etc. are all OpenType features that are entirely independent of the glyph outline language used inside of that OpenType font (truetype, cff, svg, etc.). But yes: fonts are the program, the text shaper simply follows its instruction, not the other way around. If the font does not contain `dist` instructions, nothing is going to invent them for you.

Comment: As an addendum to my earlier comment: on another computer that same Arial does *not* have `cpsp`. So YMMV; check what features *are* available before attempting to use them.